# Why cookies added when requesting remote scripts?

Tags: javascript, cookies, jsonp

Why cookies added to requests to remote scripts like JSON-P? Adding remote script should be the re-usability of the script code; not the data; or am I wrong?

Comment: Is this a question, or something you needed to get off your chest?

Comment: Because you're making a request?

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question. I don't understand what it is you are saying.

Comment: I might be missing something; I dont know; do you see any reason? I dont see one; since it should just get the script code; which does not need any session tracking

Answer (score 0):

> Why cookies added to requests to remote scripts like JSON-P?

An HTTP request is an HTTP request. If the browser has cookies for the target URI then it will send them.

Comment: It doesn't send them while cross domain get/post